# Sum the digits of a phone number using scanf

Tags: c

I want my code to prompt the user to input a phone number of form 1(xxx)-xxx-xxxx and then sum the digits of the number.  However I do not know what is wrong with my code.  See below

```
printf("Enter a phone number in 1(xxx)-xxx-xxxx format: \n");
scanf(" %*c%*c%d %d %d %*c%*c%d %d %d %*c%d %d %d %d", &i, &j, &k, &l, &m, &n, &o, &p, &q, &r);

sum = (i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r);
realsum = sum + 1;

printf("The sum of the digits = %d \n\n", realsum)
```

;

Can anyone help?  It seems to be assigning the first part of the number (xxx) entirely to i, and j is zero.  How do I get it to assign each digit to each variable one by one?

Comment: For the record I am very new to c, perhaps I am fundamentally going about this one wrong?

Comment: Do you have to use `scanf`? You might try reading the entire string and then checking it. Or use `getc` to read 1 char at a time.

Comment: I wish that were the case, however this is for a homework assignment in which we are required to use scanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `%d` keeps reading until it finds a character that can't be part of a decimal number. So if the user enters `1(123)-456-7890` then the first `%d` will set `i` to `123`.

The solution is to use `%1d`. That tells `scanf` to read a one-digit decimal number.

btw: you should verify that the return value from `scanf` is correct. In this example, the correct return value is 10. Any other number indicates that the user did not enter a valid phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You did account for the non-integer characters that the user enters, but integers are read as a whole, so `123` is not read as`1` then `2` then `3` but rather as `123`.

```
scanf(" %*c%*c%d %*c%*c%d %*c%d ", &i, &j, &k);
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems like I was misunderstanding what %*c actually did.  Thanks I will give this a try!

Comment: @Froobyflake You did not misunderstand what `%*c` does. You were using it correctly.

Comment: No, _An optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location pointed by an argument)._ @user3386109 's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Well, then I misunderstood. I will edit that out of my answer.

Comment: I agree that @user3386109 answer is the better choice.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Of course the real answer is not to use `scanf` for this, but I guess OP has to :)

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah. But I remember those days. Restricted to using what the teacher says instead of what should be used. ha ha